# Pass variable (to Ajax) that results from Js function but PHP gets it as 'NULL'

Tags: php, javascript

This function correctly checks if the iput string is already in use by comparing it to data picked up by PHP from the databese. My problem is that when I pass this variable via Ajax it returns 'NULL' but when I pass other variables they are sent correctly, so the ajax function is working. Maybe something in my function is to blame?

```
var string, code, codUp, result;
function check(){
      string="<?php echo $html; ?>";
      code = document.getElementById('this_code').value;
      codUp = code.toUpperCase();
      result=string.split(" ");      

if (document.getElementById('this_code').value === "")
{
    return false;
}
else if (result.indexOf(codUp) === -1)
{
    return false;
}
else{alert ('Code already in use.');}
};
```

AJAX

```
ajax.open('GET','agencies/gen_ag.php?action=add&name='+name+'codeUp='+codUp+'&nocomp='+nocompt_ag,true);
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['action']=='add')  {
$res_seecode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agencies WHERE EMP_CODE = '$_GET[code]'");
if(!mysql_num_rows($res_seecode))   {
    $res_add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO agencies VALUES      ('NULL','$_GET[codUp]','$_GET[name]'");

            echo 'Agencie created.';
}
```

`Var_dump();` Returns name but not codUp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the query string:

```
?action=add&name='+name+'codeUp='+codUp'&nocomp='+nocompt_ag
```

The **keys** are:

- action (**value** is "add")
- name (**value** is `name` variable's value)
- codeUp (**value** is `codUp` variable's value)
- nocomp (**value** is `nocompat_ag` variable's value)

To get the **value** sent to the server, you use the **key** with `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`.

You should use `$_GET["codeUp"]`, since the key you are using in the query string is "codeUp". `codUp` is just the Javascript variable that holds the value that is sent to the server for the "codeUp" key.

Answer (score 1):

As well as making sure the variable names match up (you're still referencing `code` in one query), you should also URL encode your values...#

```
ajax.open('GET','agencies/gen_ag.php?action=add&name='+encodeURIComponent(name)+'codeUp='+encodeURIComponent(codUp)'&nocomp='+encodeURIComponent(nocompt_ag),true);
```

Note the use of `encodeURIComponent()` - otherwise if your name contained non-url-safe characters like `?` or `&`, it would break things

Comment: Thank you for your answer it added usefull informtion.